# JavaScript to hide a div onload after 5 seconds per cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, hide, seconds

I'm developing a website in Bootstrap and need to display a banner / DIV for 5 seconds and then fade-out/hide, but need it only to show once per user / cookie session. Any ideas? I've seen similar solutions on here but for only half my request.

Comment: Where’s your existing code? Shouldn’t be that hard. Just check whether a specific cookie exists, create it, then show the banner, then hide it.

Comment: Apologies: 
JS = 
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.mydiv').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 3000); // <-- time in 3 milliseconds
</script>

HTML =     
<div class="mydiv">
    <p>Banner with text</p>
</div>

I'm a novice when it comes to writing JS, so I'd have no idea how to 'create it', etc how you put it.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Use a cookie to say  you have shown it?

Answer (score 0):

**A session is stored server side, you can't modify it with JavaScript. Sessions may contain sensitive data**.

Please put this code in head section of html page .
Though its not best way to do this in javascript rather go in backend and check session using ajax.

This cookie will live for **2 days**.

You can modify cookies using document.cookie.

```
<script>
 $(window).on("load", function(){                     // Handler when all assets (including images) are loaded
  var check = getCookie("firsttime");

  if (check == ""){
      var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");     //Suppose the  div you want to hide has id of myDiv , you can place anything you want  
      x.style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(fadeout,5000);
      var d = new Date();
      var expirydate = 2;
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expirydate*24*60*60*1000));
      var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
      document.cookie ="firsttime=no";            //now after the division is hidden cookie value is set so that we could check next day


   } 

   function fadeout() {               //This function will be called after 5 second and it will hide it and will be called if cookie value isnot set 
      var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");  
      x.style.display = "none";
     }  
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the ref firsttime used for? Do I replace with myDIV or is firsttime needed by the JS? I've having problem, it displays ok, but doesn't disappear after 5 seconds.

Comment: does only problem is not disappearing after 5 second ??? all other thing is as per your need ??

Comment: Yes, 'myDIV' displays ok using this JS code, but does not fade-out after 5 seconds. Can you help?